# Not able to extract password field in a modal window using CSS selector - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am able to click on sign in link in the start page [a link] http://imgur.com , resulting modal window of username and password field. while I was trying to extract password field on the resulted page, found no elements of username and password fields. Even I checked the source code at that instant using  `driver.getPageSource();`  and there is no sign of username or password elements. Following is the code used to extract password field from the specified URL.

```
pwd = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']"));
```

code for clicking the modal window is

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("sign in")).click();
```

Later I found that they are using iframes so I started searching the password fields in each iframe as shown below.

```
  List<WebElement> iFrames = null;
                WebElement iFramePwd=null;

                iFrames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
                if (iFrames.size() > 0) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < iFrames.size(); l++) {
                        try{ driver.switchTo().frame(l);

                        }
                        catch(NoSuchFrameException ljn){
                            System.out.println(ljn);
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                    continue;
                        }
                        try {
                            try{
                            iFramePwd = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']"));
                            }
                            catch(NoSuchElementException lkn){
                                System.out.println(lkn);
                                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                                continue;
                            }
```

Size of iframes displaying as 5 but when i try to switch to the iFrame iam always getting *NoSuchFrameException*.
Please visit the specified URL for analyzing the source code. I dont know where i am missing the point. Is there any way to get password field from the modal window. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are in different frame, select that first. Also it should be find by strategy should `xpath` not `css` as per your code snippet. And it should have `input[@type='password']`, you are missing a `@` to access type attribute value.

Comment: while switching to the frame, i am always running into NoSuchElementException. dont know where i am doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://imgur.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("sign in")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.className("cboxIframe")));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("f")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("abcd");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/input")).sendKeys("abcd");

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

If we use loop to reach the iframe, there is a problem. You don't know which ifrmae you are in because List of web elements does not grantee the exact sequence of iframe in page. For Example below code is not working and showing error "Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it"

```
List<WebElement> my_iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    // moving to inner iframe
    if(my_iframes.size() > 0){
        for(WebElement my_iframe : my_iframes){
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(my_iframe));
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("abcd");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/input")).sendKeys("abcd");
```